# How do I validate the existence of promised object keys using JSON Schema?

Tags: json, validation, testing, jsonschema

I have an object that follows the general form of:

```
{
    "ids": [5, 7, 12],
    "5": { },
    "7": { },
    "12": { },
    "23": { }
}
```

Is it possible to generate a JSON Schema that validates wheter all keys in `ids` property exist in this object and preferably ids that are not listed do not exists (ie. 23)?

Comment: I'm afraid not. You have to know all values in advance. JSON Schema is only designed to validate the structure of your JSON. Business logic will need to be written by hand.

Comment: No, json schema is a way to define a *schema*. The clue is in the name